# Why does django-startproject (by lincoln loop) create app in conf/local?

Tags: python, django

I have tested django-startproject (https://github.com/lincolnloop/django-startproject). I have read their doc and Lincoln Loop best practice, but many of their choices are still unclear for me  (the way they organize their folders, etc.).
Especially, I am quite confused by the way their bin/manage.py behave.

When I execute python bin/manage.py startapp Test, it creates the app, but instead of putting it in my project (or in apps), the directory is created in conf/local.

Is this the wanted behaviour ?

Comment: re: manage.py, if you read docs/install.rst, you'll see that you need to do a `pip install -e .`, which can install the project to your environment. Once done, you can call manage.py anywhere as long as the virtualenv is active (assuming you're using virtualenv/wrapper, which you should).

Answer (score 0):

That's because django's manage.py is by default located at the root of the project, and by default the startapp function(which is not created by the lincolnloop guys) places the apps in the current folder (where manage.py is located). this is from the official docs:

startapp  [destination]
django-admin.py startapp
Creates a Django app directory structure for the given app name in the current directory or the given destination.

you can explicitly specify where to place the app with the destination parameter.